# Oracle moving / transferring schemas from one server to another

Tags: oracle

I am having to move databases from one server to another.

Oracle on Server A has died so I can't back up the existing databases in order to move them across.

I was wondering if there is another way to move databases across servers in Oracle.

Comment: do you have an Oracle installation (minus the databases) on the other server at the same version level?

Comment: Yes, but the Oracle service wont start on the old installation so am a bit jittery about just copying everything in ORACLE_HOME over

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of coping some data and control files and installing them in a new server.

See: User-Managed Backup and Recovery Guide
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96572/toc.htm
( but look for the correct version of your database)

For example something like:

```
% cp /disk1/oracle/dbs/*.dbf /disk2/backup
% cp /disk1/oracle/dbs/*.cf /disk2/backup
% cp /disk1/oracle/network/admin/*.ora /disk2/backup
% cp /disk1/oracle/rdbms/admin/*.ora /disk2/backup
```

Answer (score 1):

If the old database shut down relatively cleanly you should be able to just copy the db files over to the new host.  "db files" includes datafiles, tempfiles, control files, and online redo logs (off the top of my head).  If you can make the directory structures on the new host the same as the old ones, you should then just be able to source the correct environment (including ORACLE_SID) and then issue a startup from SQL*Plus.  You use the phrase "Oracle service" in your answer to my question, so I'm guessing you are on Windows - I don't know how you go about re-registering it as a Windows service.

Answer (score 0):

If the servers are the same os then yes.  You can create the same directory structure on the new server as the old.  Install the oracle software and patch it to the same version as on the old window server.  Copy all the datafiles, control files, spfile , etc to their respective location on the new server.  Using the account you install oracle which has administrator privelege and belonging to the dba group, run oradim to add the service to windows to start oracle, point it to the spfile of your database.

ORADIMxx  -NEW  -SID    -INTPWD    -STARTMODE
            -PFILE

or with newer database version:

ORADIM -NEW -SID  | -ASMSID  [-SYSPWD password] 
          [-STARTMODE auto | manual] [-SRVCSTART system | demand] 
          [-PFILE filename | -SPFILE]